# What model would you suggest for this?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, autocorrelation

I have been trying to understand what model i should fit to these... I find it hard to understand the shape of ACF. What ARIMA(p,d,q) model is suitable for this data?
THANKS... :)

[image]

Comment: If you post the 500 observations, I might be able help further.

Comment: no observations available... The exercize requires to read ACF and PACF to suggest some models.

Comment: ok then post the acf and the pacf if you have them

Comment: The acf is the middle one...and pacf is on the right above....

Comment: do you have the actual acf values and the  pacf values NOT just the picture

Answer (score 0):

[image]"I find it hard to understand the shape of ACF."

If you connected the points (purple line) instead of using the vertical bars dropping down to y=0, you'd find the ACF just looks like an attenuated sinusoid, indicating oscillatory character of y.  Which is what you'd expect if you have a signal whose spectrum is peaked but a but has some width to it.  While not a clean sinusoid, its something that looks like a wobbly oscillation.

Looking at the PACF, lag up to 3 looks reasonably significant, so it suggests that an AR(3) or so is sufficient.  In order to get an oscillatory AR model, you need at least an AR(2), so this seems reasonable.  I've never used an ARIMA or an ARMA, just AR, so I'm not sure what the PACF tells us about those coefficients.

Comment: PACF is as useful as ACF even for AR models. See section "AR and MA signatures" [here](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm).